# Периодически вызываемый GetProcessTime выдаёт одно и то же значение

Tags: c++, windows, процесс

Добрый день. Поставил перед собой задачу написать маленький органайзер, отслеживающий как долго работают те или иные окна, сделал через отслеживание времени работы процесса, отвечающего за окно, следующей функцией (которая требуется для *EnumWindows*):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam)
{
wchar_t buff[255];

if ( IsWindowVisible(hWnd) )
{
    //PID -> Handle
    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &PID );
    HANDLE  pHandle = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, PID );

    //Process Time in strange format
    FILETIME strangeTime, unuse1, unuse2, unuse3;
    GetProcessTimes( pHandle, &unuse1, &unuse2, &unuse3, &strangeTime );

    //Process time in "normal" format
    SYSTEMTIME normalTime;
    FileTimeToSystemTime( &strangeTime, &normalTime );

    InternalGetWindowText( hWnd, buff, 254 );

    if( ((std::wstring)buff).size()>1 )
    {
        printf("%ls %u:%u:%u\n", buff, normalTime.wHour, normalTime.wMinute, normalTime.wSecond);
    }
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Собственно *EnumWindows* вызывается каждые 5 секунд, но время каждый раз одинаковое выводится.

---

UPD: Есть похожий топик на англоязычном стаке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107908/getprocesstimes-called-periodically-returns-the-same-results . Но там немного другая ситуация (вдруг кого натолкнёт)

---

UPD: проблема в том, какой процесс отсчитывается, если вывести все процессы и считать их время, то всё хорошо, код:

```
void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>"); //Just like char, but UNICODE (maybe)Оно

// Get a handle to the process.

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                               PROCESS_VM_READ, //Параметры доступа
                               TRUE, //Наследование ID от открытого процесса
                               processID ); //Открываем по ID

FILETIME strangeTime, unuse1, unuse2, unuse3;
GetProcessTimes( hProcess, &unuse1, &unuse2, &unuse3, &strangeTime );

SYSTEMTIME normalTime;
FileTimeToSystemTime( &strangeTime, &normalTime );

// Get the process name.

if (NULL != hProcess )
{
    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if ( EnumProcessModulesEx( hProcess, //"указатель" на процесс
                             &hMod, //Сюда мы кидаем всё, из чего состоит процесс (модули)
                             sizeof(hMod),
                             &cbNeeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL)  ) //Общий объём модулей (с учётом которые не поместились)
    {
        GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, //"указатель" на процесс
                           hMod, //рассматриваемый модуль
                           szProcessName, //сюда кладём имя
                           sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) ); //размер в символах
    }
}

// Print the process name and identifier.

_tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u) %u:%u:%u\n"), szProcessName, processID, normalTime.wHour, normalTime.wMinute, normalTime.wSecond ); // printf для TCHAR

// Release the handle to the process.

CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{
double time_counter = 0;

clock_t this_time = clock();
clock_t last_time = this_time;

while(true)
{
    this_time = clock();
    time_counter += (double)(this_time - last_time);
    last_time = this_time;

    if(time_counter > (double)(NUM_SECONDS * CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
    {
        // Get the list of process identifiers.

        time_counter -= (double)(NUM_SECONDS * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        DWORD aProcesses[1024], //PID
                cbNeeded,
                cProcesses;
        unsigned int i;

        if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
        {
            return 1;
        }


        // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

        cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

        // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

        for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
            if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
                PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
        printf("\n");

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Сейчас сверю PID и напишу конечную проблему

Comment: Последний параметр в GetProcessTime является временем, проведённое процессом в режиме пользователя. От сюда возможные проблемы.

Comment: @MrBin пробовал вывести время ядра - результат аналогичный

Comment: Для начала попробуйте поработать в отслеживаемой программе (Возможно потоки приложения висят в ждущем режиме). Либо используйте хуки для отслеживания события свертывания/развертывания окна. + Можно брать время от начала создания процесса и отсчитывать уже его (Проверка условия у вас есть).

Comment: Через перечисление процессов удаётся отследить процессы, родственные тем, что отвечают за окна, т.е. счётчик идёт, но ввиду не знания какое окно какому дочернее не могу, на данный момент, сказать как провести им связь. Могу предположить, что отсчёт не идёт, потому что процесс отвечающий за содержание окна разбит на модули, от которых и идёт активность, из-за чего не считается (если не прав, прошу поправить)